# Force create a local actor in Akka on the local JVM

Tags: akka

How to force create an actor on the local JVM (not remote) in Akka? Is this some parameter you can pass to the create function or a configuration that you need to set?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you are trying to do? By default, actors get created locally.

Comment: I want to create an actor locally on the local JVM, I dont want it to be created on a remote JVM , since I am in a clustered Akka mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your worry will not happen by `AKKA` design.

`actorOf` by default will just setup actor on local node's `actorsystem`, it will not try to setup actor on remote node even you are in cluster or remote mode.

If you want to setup actor on remote system, you will have to explicitly do follows:

**application.conf**

```
akka {
  actor {
    deployment {
      /sampleActor {
        remote = "akka.tcp://sampleActorSystem@10.192.225.100:2553"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**test.scala**

```
val actor = system.actorOf(Props[SampleActor], "sampleActor")
```

Only with above configuration, the `actorsystem` will setup the new actor on remote system.

Anyway, your worry not exist if you not do special configuration in `application.conf`, detail you can refer to [akka guide](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/remoting.html#creating-actors-remotely)

Answer (score 0):

Create an Actor with props method like below

```
public class MyActor extends AbstractActor {

    @Override
    public Receive createReceive() {
        return ReceiveBuilder.create()
                .match(Order.class, this::handleMessage)
                .build();
    }

    static Props props() {
        return Props.create(MyActor.class);
    }

    private void handleMessage(String e)
    {
        //do something with the string
    }

}
```

Then you can create the child ActorRef using.

`ActorRef childRef = actorSystem.actorOf(MyActor.props(), "myActor");`

And send messages to it like below.

```
childRef.tell(myMessage,self());
```

Comment: Isn't this the standard way to create an Actor even when it is created on a remote shard? how does this code change if it were to create a code on a remote machine?